# Need some advice whether to use static stable view or dynamic table for my project

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I am exploring the development of my first iPhone app (Xcode and Swift 3) and I need some direction and advice.  I have a need of a multiple level expanding and collapsing table.  I've attached some screens of a web app I developed to help you understand where I am going.  In my app there are main level items, which expand to show sub items, which expand to show the contents of that item. And not every sub item (when expanded) has the same elements. Some sub items have simple text fields while other items have questions with yes and no answer options.  I am so green I don't even know where to start with pulling this off in an app.  I have worked through some tutorials on expanding and collapsing dynamic cells but I am unaware if that is the best way because not all of my sub cells contain the same contents.  Should I use static cells instead?  Or is there a way to create cell templates (like include files in php) and call them in to the table and populate them when I need them?  I am lost and need some direction.  Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated. I would love tutorials as well.  I have a Lynda.com account if you are aware of tutorials there I should follow.  Thank you!

[one of the simple layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odHxV.png)

[a different layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5CnE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/ExpandingTableView) lib could help you.

Comment: That did help Bence, thank you! However I am trying to better understand how to then customize the look of each cell and also create multiple children of that parent cell that also expand and collapse.  Do you have any insight for me?